Buildroot fails to compile host-heimdal
This is my defconfig slightly modified from configs/raspberrypi3_64_defconfig:
$ cat defconfig 
BR2_aarch64=y
BR2_cortex_a53=y
BR2_ARM_FPU_VFPV4=y

# patches
BR2_GLOBAL_PATCH_DIR="board/raspberrypi/patches"
BR2_DOWNLOAD_FORCE_CHECK_HASHES=y

BR2_SYSTEM_DHCP="eth0"

# Linux headers same as kernel, a 6.6 series
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_6_6=y

BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_CXX=y

BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL_LOCATION="$(call github,raspberrypi,linux,576cc10e1ed50a9eacffc7a05c796051d7343ea4)/linux-576cc10e1ed50a9eacffc7a05c796051d7343ea4.tar.gz"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG="bcmrpi3"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME="broadcom/bcm2710-rpi-3-b broadcom/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus broadcom/bcm2710-rpi-cm3"

BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_NEEDS_HOST_OPENSSL=y

BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_BOOTCODE_BIN=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_VARIANT_PI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_CONFIG_FILE="board/raspberrypi3-64/config_3_64bit.txt"

# Required tools to create the SD image
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_DOSFSTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENIMAGE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_MTOOLS=y

# Filesystem / image
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="120M"
# BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_TAR is not set
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT="board/raspberrypi3-64/post-build.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT="board/raspberrypi3-64/post-image.sh"

# Enable compressed kernel module support
BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_SHOW_OTHERS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_KMOD_TOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XZ=y
BR2_PACKAGE_KMOD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_KMOD_XZ=y

issuing make, this is the last lines of the output:
checking for library containing yywrap... -ll
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for ln -s or something else... ln -s
checking for __attribute__... no
checking for ld --version-script... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wno-error=enum-conversion... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -Wno-unused-but-set-variable... yes
checking for openldap... no
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for MICROHTTPD... no
checking for CJWT... no
checking for CJSON... no
checking for sqlite3... no
checking for libintl... no
checking for crypto library... included libhcrypto
checking if compiling threadsafe libraries... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for size_t... no
checking for egrep... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for pid_t... no
checking for uid_t... no
checking for gid_t... no
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for standards.h... no
checking for netinet/ip.h... no
checking for netinet/tcp.h... no
checking for egrep -e... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for /home/mark/dev/buildroot/output/host/bin/ccache /usr/bin/gcc  options needed to detect all undeclared functions... cannot detect
configure: error: in '/home/mark/dev/buildroot/output/build/host-heimdal-f4faaeaba371fff3f8d1bc14389f5e6d70ca8e17':
configure: error: cannot make /home/mark/dev/buildroot/output/host/bin/ccache /usr/bin/gcc  report undeclared builtins
See 'config.log' for more details
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:279: /home/mark/dev/buildroot/output/build/host-heimdal-f4faaeaba371fff3f8d1bc14389f5e6d70ca8e17/.stamp_configured] Errore 1
make: *** [Makefile:83: _all] Errore 2

I searched inside the xconfig tool for host-heimdal but I found nothing.
Why does it fail? I mean, I didn't change nothing about its configuration.
UPDATE

Buildroot version:2024.08-rc3
Download method: git clone
Host version: Ubuntu 24.04


Could you provide: Buildroot version, host distribution and version, contents of the config.log file in output/build/host-heimdal-f4faaeaba371fff3f8d1bc14389f5e6d70ca8e17 folder ?

@ThomasPetazzoni question updated, thanks. I cannot provide the whole content of config.log since it has a size of 232k and the size of a question can be 30k only. Also, external links are discouraged here (downvotes/close question).

Is there a specific part of the file that might help to see?

There's something wrong with your report, because the build output shows that ccache is used while your defconfig doesn't have BR2_CCACHE=y.

@Arnout you're right. But it is just a difference in time when I enabled it and copied the outputs. At first it was disabled, but after the host-heimdal failed, I tried to enabled it and issued another make. If you think it may be the culprit I can clean the build and launch it again.

It looks like it's actually an issue with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS. BTW it's weird that host-heimdal is being built at all, it is only a dependency of samba4 which you don't have enabled either.

@Arnout I'm sure I didn't select samba4 since I don't need it, but as you said that I removed the whole buildroot directory, downloaded and configured it again (with the same packages) and now it seems it is building... in any case I appreciated you answer!

The root cause is a bug in heimdal's autoconf macros.
As a quick workaround, you can probably add ac_cv_sys_large_files=1 ac_cv_sys_file_offset_bits=64 to HOST_HEIMDAL_CONF_ENV in heimdal.mk.
The problem is that heimdal's configure script uses the AC_SYS_LARGEFILE macro, and then uses its internal ac_cv_sys_large_files and ac_cv_sys_file_offset_bits variables. These variables were removed in a recent update of that macro.
The proper fix is probably to remove that special handling of largefile in upstream heimdal's configure script. But I don't know why that was introduced in the first place...
